# SQLite3 Integer and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a column of type INTEGER to which I insert a value using the following statement:

```
connection.execute("INSERT INTO ActiveTable (IDPK, Time) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
```

But the data stores unicode in the format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

How can an INTEGER field store a unicode formatted timestamp? Why doesn't an error get thrown here?

Comment: try int(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)?

Comment: There's no int casting in SQL statements.

Comment: What I meant was convert it before you put it in your sql

Comment: Ah. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is a SQL shortcut and when outside of a SQL statement it means nothing in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite uses dynamic typing. It does not enforce data type constraints. So it do the saving-is-first strategy, saving you data is the the main job and when the data type is not matching the defined type SQLite would  converts it in some particular principles.

More info: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3
https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity